# ld.exe cannot find -lfl

Tags: c, mingw, shakespeare-lang

I'm using mingw to compile the Shakespeare Programming Language and during the compilation I get the following error.

```
c:/users/neil/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
cannot find -lfl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make: *** [spl2c] Error 1
```

I searched it in Google, and found a few people have trouble ld.exe but most of them were having issues with other flags and could not find anything useful.
What does the `-lfl` flag do, and how can I fix this issue?
EDIT: I have downloaded the flex binaries from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/ and added them to my path.

Here is my `Makefile`:

```
########################################################################
#
# SPL, the Shakespeare Programming Language
#
# Copyright (C) 2001 Karl Hasselström and Jon Åslund
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or (at
# your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
# WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
# General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307,
# USA.
#
########################################################################

NAME     = spl
VERSION  = 1.2.1
DISTNAME = $(NAME)-$(VERSION)

# compiler commands 
AR      = ar
CC      = gcc
LEX     = flex
RANLIB  = ranlib
TAR     = tar
YACC    = bison

INCLUDEPATH = include
EDITORPATH  = editor
EXAMPLEPATH = examples

# source / outputs
MAKESCANNERINCLUDE = $(wildcard $(INCLUDEPATH)/*.{wordlist,metaflex})

# compiler flags
YACCFLAGS = --verbose
CCFLAGS   = -O2 -Wall -LC:/Users/Neil/Downloads/Exes/flex-2.5.4a-1-bin
LEXFLAGS  = -Cem

.PHONY: all clean examples install libspl tar
all: install examples

examples: install
    $(MAKE) -C $(EXAMPLEPATH) all

grammar.tab.h grammar.tab.c: grammar.y
    $(YACC) $(YACCFLAGS) -d $<

grammar.tab.o: grammar.tab.c grammar.tab.h telma.h
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $<

install: spl2c libspl.a spl.h
    mkdir -p spl/bin spl/include spl/lib
    cp -pf spl2c spl/bin
    cp -pf spl.h spl/include
    cp -pf libspl.a spl/lib

libspl.a: libspl.o strutils.o
    $(AR) rc $@ $^
    $(RANLIB) $@

libspl.o: libspl.c spl.h
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $<

makescanner: makescanner.o
    $(CC) $< $(CCFLAGS) -o $@

makescanner.o: makescanner.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $<

scanner.c: scanner.l
    $(LEX) $(LEXFLAGS) -t $< > $@

scanner.l: makescanner $(MAKESCANNERINCLUDE)
    $< $(INCLUDEPATH) > $@ #remove ./

scanner.o: scanner.c grammar.tab.h telma.h
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $<

spl2c: grammar.tab.o scanner.o strutils.o
    $(CC) $^ $(CCFLAGS) -lfl -o $@

strutils.o: strutils.c strutils.h
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $<

tar: clean
    mkdir -p $(DISTNAME)
    cp `find . -type f -maxdepth 1` $(DISTNAME)
    cp -r $(INCLUDEPATH) $(DISTNAME)
    cp -r $(EDITORPATH) $(DISTNAME)
    cp -r $(EXAMPLEPATH) $(DISTNAME)
    $(TAR) zcvf $(DISTNAME).tar.gz $(DISTNAME)

# clean-up function
clean:
    rm -f *~ $(EDITORPATH)/*~ $(INCLUDEPATH)/*~ *.l *.o *.a core grammar.output grammar.tab.h grammar.tab.c scanner.c makescanner spl2c *.tar.gz
    rm -rf spl $(DISTNAME)
    $(MAKE) -C $(EXAMPLEPATH) clean
```

Comment: `libfl` is Flex's shared library. Flex is a parser. `-lfl` means 'link to the `fl` library'. Do you have flex installed?

Comment: You probably have a package named `flex` missing or incorrectly installed.

Comment: I downloaded flex binaries from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/ and added it to my PATH.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `flex` to your `PATH` won't make the flex *library* available to the linker, `ld.exe`. You may need to add the flex library directory to an [`-L <directory>` command line option to your compiler](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options).

Comment: So would it be ld -L <directory>?

Comment: What does your `Makefile` look like? Chances are good you can just add `-L /path/to/flex/directory` to your `CFLAGS` variable.

Comment: To the bin directory of the flex directory or the flex directory?

Comment: Here's the updated makefile. It doesn't work ad gives me the same error. http://pastebin.com/xNy9iu15

Answer (score 1):

`try -LC:\pathtoflexlibdirectory` where `libfl.a` file is